# Check if message is deleted from azure queue

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-queues

I have processor that takes messages from storage queue. This message has some visibillity timeout. But sometimes processor takes more time than timeout, so another instance of processor takes message to process again (second time it is not possible to go through all flow in processor as I have some validation). Second time message is processed faster than and became deleted before all flow is finished in first time.

But when flow is finished it also wants to delete message that is already deleted.
As result I get error:

> Message="Unable to translate bytes [92] at index -1 from specified
>   code page to Unicode.

Is it possible to check if message is delete before trying to delete it second time?

Comment: Please specify if you're using Azure Storage Queue or Azure Service Bus Queue (I am guessing that you're using Storage Queues).

Comment: @GauravMantri, your guess is correct

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to try is making the visibility timeout long enough that you can be sure the processing will finish before the timeout expires.

If that isn't an option or if you want additional safety, you can use `CloudQueue.UpdateMessage()` to increase the visibility timeout on the message.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.updatemessageasync?view=azure-dotnet